# deleting a column of matrice in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 matrices in MATLAB. I want to delete columns of first matrix in which there is at least an element bigger than 5 or smaller than zero. then I want to delete that column from second matrix too.how is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to turn `MxN` matrix to be `MxN-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have 2 matrices `A` and `B` and we want to delete columns containing at least one element fulfilling `a<=0 #or# a>=5`. In other words we want to keep columns where all alements fulfill `a>0 #and# a<5`.

```
Cols=find(min(A) > 0 & max(A) < 5)    % find columns
newA=A(:,Cols);                       % pick columns of A
newB=B(:,Cols);                       % pick columns of B
```

---

**EDIT**

According to Dan's comment: Code above is slower but easier to edit.

You can also use

```
newA=A(:,min(A)>0 & max(A)<5);
newB=A(:,min(A)>0 & max(A)<5);
```

which is faster but harder to edit.

```
Cols=min(A)>0 & max(A)<5;
NewA=A(:,Cols);
NewB=B(:,Cols);
```

Last part also works.

Comment: There is no need to use `find` here, logical indexing is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You first make a mask of where there are elements larger than 5. For ease call your matrices A and B.

```
maskA = A>5;
```

Then say that you are only interested in columns

```
maskAcolumn = any(maskA,1);
```

So maskAcolumn is 1 if the column has a value over 5 and 0 if not. Now remove the columns

```
A(:,maskAcolumn)=[];
B(:,maskAcolumn)=[];
```

In case B is larger than A, use "find", to find the places, and then use that array in stead.